# What method is called when iPhone app is terminated?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am making a client server application for the iPhone and would like to know which method is called when the iPhone application is terminated. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method relating to application lifecycle are `UIApplicationDelegate` methods. The two you want are:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

If on a multitasking device, `applicationDidEnterBackground:` will be called instead of `applicationWillTerminate:`. In most cases, you can perform the same code in both callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

in your appdelegate

Answer (score 0):

The method applicationWillTerminate gets called when your application is being shut down. But the applicationDidEnterBackground/applicationWillResignActive methods are (now) infinitely more useful.

Answer (score 0):

`-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` in your application delegate will be called. Check [this blog post with chart](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/) that describes in detail what messages will be sent during launch, termination and when transitioning between background and foreground.